# how to change multiple loop of array in one array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My current format of array which is coming in loop is something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [studentID] => 1
        [ParentID] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [studentID] => 2
        [ParentID] => 1
     )
)

Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [studentID] => 5
        [ParentID] => 1
     )

     [1] => Array (
         [studentID] => 7
         [ParentID] => 3
      )
)
```

and the same format of array repeats for all classes

Can I change it in single array so that it can be fetched in a table on basis of studentID?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

array_merge can take variable number of arguments, so with a little call_user_func_array trickery you can pass your $result array to it:

`$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);`

This basically run like if you would have typed:

`$merged = array_merge($result[0], $result[1], .... $result[n]);`

Now with 5.6, we have the ... operator to unpack arrays to arguments, so you can:

`$merged = array_merge(...$result);`

And have the same results

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at multidimensional array.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

What I meant is I don't think you need to change it into a single array as it will mess up the data. As your are making the table, you should loop through the array like this:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Student ID</th>';
echo '<th>Parent ID</th>';
echo '</tr>';
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $array[$i]['studentID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $array[$i]['ParentID'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I hope this is what you are trying to accomplish.